# New position after objects are rotated by \rotatebox

Tags: tcolorbox, rotating

The option "`origin=lb`" in the macro `\rotatebox` which comes frome the package `graphicx`, means the object will rotates by its left-hand bottom.
So the "typeset-1 & typeset-2" in the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\noindent
\parindent=0pt
\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{some text}\\[3em]% typeset-2

\rotatebox{0}{% typeset-3
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.7\textwidth,height=6em]
    the left side of this box alligns well with the left end of the headrule.
  \end{tcolorbox}
}\\
%
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{% typeset-4
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.7\textwidth,height=6em]
    As the option "origin=lb" is used, the right side of this rotated box should align with the left end of the headrule, but it does not.
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

should be like this:
[image]
but get this:
[image]
When the object comes from `tcolorbox`(see typeset-3 & typeset-4 in the above code), they have the same problem.
Is this a problem of `\rotatebox` or other? How to get a typeset effect like the first figure?

Comment: If you want this kind of positioning have a look at the `xcoffins` package.

Comment: The width of the rotated box is taken into account. So it does not overlay previous text or run into the left margin. You have to hide the width of the rotated box: `\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{some text}}` or  the height of the contents: `\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\smash{some text}}`. Note that the results would be different if there would be a descender like in "my text".

Comment: @ esdd very simple and perfect solution! Anywhere finds the working principal of the \smash?

Answer (score 2):

The width of the rotated box is taken into account. So it does not overlay previous text or run into the left margin. You have to hide the width of the rotated box:

```
\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{some text}}
```

or the height of the contents:

```
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\smash{some text}}.
```

Note that the results of these suggestions would be different if there is a descender like in "my text".

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}% <- parskip instead parindent, only for the example
%\usepackage{showframe}% <- to show the pagelayout, only for the example
\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{some text}\\[3em]% typeset-2

\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{some text}}% typeset-2

\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\smash{some text}}% typeset-2

\bigskip
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{my text}}% typeset-2

\makebox[0pt][l]{some text}% typeset-1
\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\smash{my text}}% typeset-2

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]